# Should I use "the tag (tag-name)" or "the (tag-name) tag"?

Tags: word-order

Here in Stack Exchange network (probably mostly in meta discussions and in chat) we often discuss about tags.

I wonder which of these two forms is the correct one: "the tag (tag-name)" or "the (tag-name) tag". What I mean is which of these two sentences is correct? (Or are they both correct?)

- This question should have the tag [word-order](/questions/tagged/word-order).
- This question should have the [word-order](/questions/tagged/word-order) tag.

Just by comparing what other people commonly use, it seems that that latter is more frequent. If I search in the posts on meta.SE, I get for these two possibilities:

- 2 results for [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+tag+status-completed%22), 2 results for [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+tag+status-declined%22), 6 results for [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+tag+feature-request%22);
- 32 results for [status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+status-completed+tag%22), 11 results for [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+status-declined+tag%22), 47 results for [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+feature-request+tag%22).

(I wanted to try at least some tags which I guessed appear quite frequently in posts.)

Comment: They're pretty much equivalent, and in your *specific* context I see no particular reason to prefer one over the other (apart from possible *consistency* with other instances in the same "body" of text). But if I consider something like *Let's assign this item the XXXX tag*, this strongly implies *that such a tag does in fact exist* (has already been defined and/or used). The alternative *Let's assign this item the tag XXXX* carries no such implication, and could even be said to imply that this item will be the *first* to use the specified tag.